# SMS Broadcast Receiver not working after restart

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get phone number and phonebook name from a text message. When I run it from application, and close application, it works, but, when I restart my mobile, it doesn't work. Anybody?

```
public class IncomingSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String queryString = "@zovi";
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
        if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context, IncomingSMSService.class);
            _context.startService(intent);
            Bundle bundle = _intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                    String msg = message.getMessageBody();
                    Log.i("Poruka", msg);
                    String to = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String contactName = TelefonUtils.getContact(_context, to);
                    Log.i("Od", contactName + "\n" + to);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<receiver android:name=".telefon.receivers.IncomingSMSReceiver"
          android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: did you exit your application before restarting the device?  What version of Android are you running on there?

Comment: create another receiver for BOOT_COMPLETE. and register your msg receiver in it ..

Comment: also add this action `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in Intent filtert

Comment: @Miljan Vulovic if my answer helps you pls mark as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` try to add  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` action under `IncomingSMSReceiver` receiver tag.

To start `Services` or  `BroadcastReceiver` automatically after the Android system restarts or starts you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to the Android `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` system event.

Try this code.

```
<receiver android:name=".telefon.receivers.IncomingSMSReceiver"
 android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
       <intent-filter android:priority="500">
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you have tried `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` then it will not work in your case because you forgot to add `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent in your
`IncomingSMSReceiver` and it will work only in case of `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` because of if condition you have used in `IncomingSMSReceiver`. so change if condition from

```
if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
```

to

```
if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED) || _intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
```

and also define `private static final String BOOT_COMPLETED = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";` in `IncomingSMSReceiver`. Below is full code of `IncomingSMSReceiver`.

Change your `IncomingSMSReceiver` code to this:

```
public class IncomingSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String queryString = "@zovi";
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String BOOT_COMPLETED = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
        if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED) || _intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context, IncomingSMSService.class);
            _context.startService(intent);
            Bundle bundle = _intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                    String msg = message.getMessageBody();
                    Log.i("Poruka", msg);
                    String to = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String contactName = TelefonUtils.getContact(_context, to);
                    Log.i("Od", contactName + "\n" + to);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when your phone restarts it will receive `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and call your `IncomingSMSReceiver` receiver then it will start your `IncomingSMSService`.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the receiver starts after phone reboots.

Add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in `intent-filter`

Comment: Try adding boot completed permission in your manifest file like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Answer (score 2):

I used this in my project, find this from [Android SMS Receive Listener](https://gist.github.com/chathudan/127b7b3715687328d95e)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* @@author Chathura Wijesinghe <cdanasiri@gmail.com> 
* 
* <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
*/
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED         = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private static ArrayList<SMSReceivedListner> smsListner = new ArrayList<SMSReceivedListner>();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    if (action.equals(SMSReceiver.SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        final boolean smsValid = extras != null;

        if (smsValid) {
            //Create SMSMessages from PDUs in the Bundle
            final Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            //Assemble
            final ArrayList<Long> vibrations = new ArrayList<Long>();

            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                for (SMSReceivedListner smsReceivedListner : smsListner )
                    smsReceivedListner.message(message);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void addSMSListner(SMSReceivedListner listner){
    smsListner.add(listner);
}

public static void removeSMSListner(SMSReceivedListner listner){
    smsListner.remove(listner);
}

public interface SMSReceivedListner{
    public void message(SmsMessage message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it should have worked.Is weird that its not working.

Remove android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" from the broadcast receiver.It is not required.

Try increasing the priority `android:priority="2147483647"` to maximum.It might be some other app is consuming the event or try the below solution.

Add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in your intent filter and see if it works.

Something like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".telefon.receivers.IncomingSMSReceiver"
          android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: tried that, not working. Also, tried calling activity from BOOT_COMPLETED receiver, also not working...

Comment: @MiljanVulovic did u add the permission

Comment: yes. I Have one receiver that is BOOT_COMPLETED, it works, just this incoming message isnt

Comment: should I create a service for this?

Comment: make the priority to maximum.

Comment: nothin, priority set to 999, thats the max, nothing.

Comment: Maybe you could try priority of `2147483647` its not recommended, but you could test. Also have you started your app once atleast after restart.

Comment: @MiljanVulovic also try adding permissions in the top of the Manifest as a direct child of the Manifest,i.e., above the `Application` tag. And do you have SMSGo or some other app for receiving SMS Messages (IMPORTANT). Especially GO SMS Pro?

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE tried with that priority you put there, no go.I have put the permission as a direct child to manifest, still nothing. No, I am testing this on rooted samsung galaxy s2 plus, i put it like a system app, only services are here, no opening application. If you have other proposition, please, tell me, cause i dont know where to look anymore

Comment: Its weird.I guess some other app is consuming the event.Try to make your app as default sms handler and see if it works.

Comment: @Miljan Vulovic You mean no activity? U don't have an activity? from android 3.1+ u require an activity. It's a security policy. Also try it on a non root phone if you have one

Comment: @rupeshjain how to make it default sms handler?

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE its a ssystem application, everything else works just fine, only this sms receiver.

Comment: What i mean is you do have at least one activity right?

Comment: I'm replicating this sms app of yours. All it will do is sense an SMS and open the activity. Unfortunately I'm on travel and cannot receive an SMS at the moment. I'll try to get another phone and try it if I can. But I beleive the problem is only in your phone that is the device.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" from the receiver declaration. No BOOT_COMPLETED or other permission are required.

Answer (score 1):

explicitly set `exported` to `true` in your manifest as an element for the `Receiver`

```
 android:exported="true"
```

and make sure both of your application element and receiver element are enabled

```
android:enabled="true"
```

Comment: try this sir, add a Log as the first line right in onReceive and see if it gets called, if it does then its prolly your code, then we can digg there@VulovicVukasin

Comment: have added logging on start of every receiver. Everything gets called after reboot only sms receiver doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast code seems to be okay and Make sure that you are using any other SMS apps in your device(May this SMS Broadcast might interrupting your apps Broadcast) . If you are not using no other SMS apps then it should work otherwise un-install that SMS app and try once.

and also check you have added the following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Hope this will work.